# Файл не докачивается полностью

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, клиент-сервер

Когда пытаюсь скачать файл с сервера, файл начинает качаться в корректной папке, но почему то не хочет продолжать качаться. Почему? Вот код:

```
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
        {
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += delegate(object send, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs a) { pb.Value = a.ProgressPercentage; };
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += delegate(object send, AsyncCompletedEventArgs a) { MessageBox.Show("Загрузка билда завершена"); pb.Visible = false; };
            pb.Visible = true;
            if(File.Exists(FolderDialog.SelectedPath + "/" + version))
                File.Delete(FolderDialog.SelectedPath + "/" + version);
            client.DownloadFile("http://хост.домен/" + version, FolderDialog.SelectedPath + "/" + version);
        }
```

Comment: А если убрать обе привязки ивентов, то догружает?

Comment: @VladD Тоже самое. Очень странно. С браузера нормально качается

Comment: Исключений не выкидывает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была с потоками. Надо писать без using и место DownloadFile надо использовать DownloadFileAsync. Так же в эвентах не использовать анонимные методы. Всё прекрасно заработало:

```
        string n = ((Button)sender).Name;
        versionD = n.Equals("LoadLastVersionbutton") ? "S1.noext" : n.Equals("LoadPreLastVersionButton") ? "S2.noext" : n.Equals("LoadLastTestVersionbutton") ? "T1.noext" : "T2.noext";
        pbd = (ProgressBar)this.Controls.Find(versionD.Equals("S1.noext") ? "LastPB" : versionD.Equals("S2.noext") ? "PreLastPB" : versionD.Equals("T1.noext") ? "TestPB" : "PreTestPB", true)[0];
        FolderDialog.ShowDialog();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri url = new Uri("http://блаблабла.домен" + versionD);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += OnProgressDownloadChenged;
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += OnDownloadComplete;
        pbd.Visible = true;
        if (File.Exists(FolderDialog.SelectedPath + "/" + versionD))
            File.Delete(FolderDialog.SelectedPath + "/" + versionD);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(url, FolderDialog.SelectedPath + "/" + versionD);
```